# Positioning a Background Picture in CSS

Tags: html, css

Probably a simple question but ive looked through a couple of other topics and none are having same problem i'm having. I'm trying to position a slogan at the top right of my page (Creating a revision website for practice).

```
                <div id="tagline">

                    <h3>Exams Made Easy</h3>

                </div>

#tagline {
background: url(images/Slogan.jpg) no-repeat;
}
```

I placed the h3 there originally just so i could plan the page out, but if i delete the h3 line it will take the jpg with it. I'm trying to position the slogan jpg top right aligned centrally with my logo which is top left.

My problems are: When i delete the h3 line so i just have the jpg; both the h3 AND the jpg will disappear.

Also, I am trying to use background-position to place the slogan top right, I can place it on the right using background-position but even at 0px in the y direction it will still be placed under the logo.

Thanks.

EDIT Header HTML:

```
            <div id="header">

                <div id="logo">
                </div>

                <div id="tagline">
                </div>
                <div style="clear:both"></div>

                <ul id="menu">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Explanations</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Problems</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Products</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
                    <div style="clear:both"></div>
                </ul>

            </div> <!--End Header-->
```

Comment: Where is the logo in your markup?

Comment: It's above the tagline in the markup. When i swap them round the inverse happens, The tagline is top right then the logo is left but below the tagline.

Comment: '     <div id="logo">
     </div>

     <div id="tagline">
     </div>'

Comment: Did you try using `background-position: 10px 5px;` for positioning it 10px from the left and 5px from top?

Comment: Hi Alejandro, Yes i tried that; The slogan is in the right position in the x direction (towards the right) but in the y direction it will always sit slightly below the logo instead of in line with it. Not sure what to do as i did not have this problem on my other test website. Thanks

Comment: I have included the code of the whole header as an edit. I have also found that if i delete the first "<div style="clear:both"></div>", the unordered list will actually move above the slogan into the top right gap that i am trying to move the slogan into!

Comment: @malonej and using a negative Y position? `background-position: 10px -5px;`?

Comment: I tried that and the slogan simply disappears :(

Comment: If i reduce the width of my logo to about 250px (the logo is about 350px wide) the slogan will then move up into the space, so it must be that.. Not sure how to fix that though. Combined the logo & the slogan are about 750px wide, is that too wide for a webpage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the h3 tag, your div has no content and consequently no height.  You don't see your background because there is no background to display for a 0px height div.

You could try giving your div a height (or min-height) in your css rule.

To address the positioning of your images, if you want a solution which uses background images, you might try two overlapping divs. Essentially, you can set a negative margin-top on your second div (equal to the height of the first div) to pull it up and overlap the first div.